# How should I create my GUID?

Tags: php, guid

I'm going to be uploading images to a system and need them to be referenced by a non-sequential unique ID. I've read a little about GUIDs, and I'm wondering what the best approach to making one in PHP is. Should I md5() the current timestamp and salt it, or will PHP's uniqueid (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function be sufficient enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Yikes! I forgot about this ancient answer of mine. To clarify confusion created by my naivety (consistent with the comments made below): MD5 (like most useful hashes, by their nature) are *not* injective, so their output is not guaranteed to be unique for all inputs.

If hash collisions are an issue (in this case, they are), using this technique will require checking, after hashing, whether an identical key has already been generated.

---

Since [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) uses the current time in microseconds to generate the guid, there is virtually no chance you'll ever run into the same one twice.

So if you're just using it to make unique filenames, uniqid() will be sufficient. If you want to prevent users from guessing the guid, you might as well make it harder and md5 it as well.

Comment: I like the idea of md5'ing it :)

Comment: @BraedenP: No, MD5 is a surjective function as it maps an infinite set of input values to an finite set of output values.

Comment: Time-based functons are only guaranteed unique so long as the time function itself monotonic. Datetime changes, DST and timezones make such an assumption invalid..

Comment: No-no-no, if you want to add md5 - just append it. Applying md5 to uuid reduces it's security.

Answer (score 6):

GUID is Microsoft's version of UUID. PHP's uniqid is version 4 of UUID. Definitely good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I also want to create guid for calling .net api and this function generate a key in guid format and it works for me

```
function generateGuid($include_braces = false) {
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
        if ($include_braces === true) {
            return com_create_guid();
        } else {
            return substr(com_create_guid(), 1, 36);
        }
    } else {
        mt_srand((double) microtime() * 10000);
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));

        $guid = substr($charid,  0, 8) . '-' .
                substr($charid,  8, 4) . '-' .
                substr($charid, 12, 4) . '-' .
                substr($charid, 16, 4) . '-' .
                substr($charid, 20, 12);

        if ($include_braces) {
            $guid = '{' . $guid . '}';
        }

        return $guid;
    }
}
```